# Spring Boot webservice (REST) - How to change JUnit 5 tests from basic authentication to OAuth2 (Keycloak)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, junit5

I have a `Spring Boot` webservice with `REST` controllers and with basic authentication (username and password).

On this base I developed JUnit 5 test.

Now I switch to `OAuth2`, currently trying the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` grant type.

What do I need to change on my `JUnit 5` tests to run now with `OAuth2`?
Of course, before running my new tests with `OAuth2` I have to start first `Keycloak`, afterwards the tests.

Following is my setup for the current basic authentication and the new OAuth2.

> BASIC AUTHENTICATION (old implementation)

On my webservice side the web security config class looks like following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            
            .antMatchers("/articles/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            // More antMatchers...
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable();
    }    

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails admin = User
            .withUsername("admin")
            .password("{noop}" + "admin123")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
            
        // More users...

        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();

        userDetailsManager.createUser(admin);
        ...

        return userDetailsManager;
    }   
}
```

For the JUnit 5 tests I allways use the user `admin`, for example

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithUserDetails(value = "admin")
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MyRestControllerMockMvcTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @BeforeAll
    public void init(ApplicationContext appContext) throws Exception {
        TestUtils.setupSecurityContext(appContext);
        
        // some initialization
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    public void cleanup(ApplicationContext appContext) throws Exception {
        TestUtils.setupSecurityContext(appContext);
        
        // some cleanup
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getSomeInformationFromMyRestController() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = TestUtils.performGet(mockMvc, "...REST controller endpoint...", status().isOk());

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ... = objectMapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), ...);

        assertNotNull(...);
    }    
}

public class TestUtils {
    public static void setupSecurityContext(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        UserDetailsService uds = (UserDetailsService) appContext.getBean("userDetailsService");
        UserDetails userDetails = uds.loadUserByUsername ("admin");
        Authentication authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
    }   

    public static MvcResult performGet(MockMvc mockMvc, String endpoint, ResultMatcher status) throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get(endpoint))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status)
            .andReturn();

        return mvcResult;
    }
}
```

Looking right now on the test setup in `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` I'm not sure all of a sudden if I have to do

```
TestUtils.setupSecurityContext(appContext);
```

because now I use

```
@WithUserDetails(value = "admin")
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```

on the class. Just curious if the tests would still run without `TestUtils.setupSecurityContext(appContext);`, will try.

---

> OAUTH2 (new implementation, replacing basic authentication above)

application.properties

```
...
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8183/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

With `OAuth2` I changed the web security config class in my webservice (resource server) as following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/articles/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            // More antMatchers...          
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
            ;

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new MyRoleConverter());
        
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }    

    public class MyRoleConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
        @Override
        public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(final Jwt jwt) {
            jwt.getClaims().get("realm_access");
            
            // Create roles

            return ...;
        }
    }
}
```

My users are now defined in `Keycloak`.
`Keycloak` is configured to use `Resource Owner Password Credentials`.

Comment: For the most part, the manner of authentication doesn't matter to your controllers, so I wonder if you'd have to do anything different at all. Are you having trouble?

Comment: Would it be possible for running the tests to entirely desable security? How?

Comment: Changing this annotation to @AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false) on a test class, it doesn't know of 'secure'. Spring Boot 2.5.4, Junit 5.

Answer (score 0):

@jzheaux is right (sure, he's spring-security team member...).

Changes will occure in your security configuration but the test won't change ... for the most part: You'll probably want to have an `Authentication` of the right type in your test security-context.

If your new security configuration populates security-context with `JwtAuthenticationToken`, it would be nice to have `JwtAuthenticationToken` in test security-context too. `@WithUserDetails(value = "admin")` won't build `JwtAuthenticationToken`.

You should have a look at [this lib](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) I wrote and specifically at [`@WithMockJwtAuth`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-addons/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/test/annotations/WithMockJwtAuth.java). Usage is demonstrated [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/1d6638d4e2478bfa7748e46bca1a56b602c74973/spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc/jwtauthenticationtoken/web/JwtAuthenticationTokenGreetingControllerAnnotatedTest.java#L94):

```java
    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL", claims = @OpenIdClaims(sub = "Ch4mpy"))
    public void greetJwtCh4mpy() throws Exception {
        api.get("/greet").andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }
```

P.S.
You'll find in this same git repo samples for other kind of `Authentication` better adapted to OIDC than `JwtAuthenticationToken` like `KeycloakAuthenticationToken` (written by Keycloak team for Keycloak exclusively) or `OidcAuthentication` (written by myself for any OpenID Connect complient authorization server), along with `@WithMockKeycloakAuth` and `@WithMockOidcAuth`